# cannot change label text using New keyword

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change the text on a label using two methods, the second method for some reason doesn't work. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

First method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim lbl As Label

        lbl = Label1

        With lbl
        .Text = "Changed"
        End With

End Sub
```

Second method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lbl As New Label

    With lbl
        .Text = "Changed."
    End With

    Label1 = lbl

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question. Specifically, it would help if you explained "the second method for some reason doesn't work." Is there an error? How does the output differ from expected?

Comment: You can skip pretty much all of this and only use the line `Label1.Text = "Changed"`.

Comment: @laancelot I know, I just want to know why the second method doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @DCTID I get no errors running both codes, but the second code does not change the text of Label1.

Comment: @VoidLT Sorry for misjudging you, it looked like one of the new users questions. I get what you mean, and it's a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the second technique, and that's why it doesn't work.

First, the new label has no position.

Second, the new label isn't part of the form's control list (and won't be drawn).

And third, the old "Label1" is still referenced in the form's controls (it would be hiding the new control anyway).

For method 2 to work, it would have to look like this:

```
    Dim lbl As New Label()
    lbl.Text = "Changed"
    lbl.Location = Label1.Location
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    Me.Controls.Remove(Label1)
    Label1 = lbl
```

If you're wondering why it needs so much micromanagement, the answer is that in the first method, all these things are already dealt with since you're using the existing Label1. By creating a brand new label, you're taking over the whole job.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.